# Setting up nginx Reverse Proxy with Let's Encrypt SSL for WordPress

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxy

I have a setup where I have a proxy server on 10.10.0.100 and a webserver on 10.20.0.100. The proxy server is running nginx as a reverse proxy, and the webserver has nginx and php-fpm serving a WordPress site. I would like to implement Let's Encrypt SSL certificates using Certbot for both the reverse proxy and the webserver.

Here are the main components of my setup:

- Proxy Server: 10.**10**.0.100
- Web Server: 10.**20**.0.100
- Reverse Proxy: nginx on the proxy server
- Webserver: nginx and php-fpm on the web
  server WordPress running on the web server

Questions:

Certificate Location:
Where should I create the SSL certificate using Certbot? Should I generate the certificate on the reverse proxy (10.10.0.100) or the webserver (10.20.0.100)?

Reverse Proxy Config:
What should be the nginx configuration on the reverse proxy server for the reverse proxy setup? How can I configure it to handle SSL termination and forward requests to the web server?

Webserver Config:
How should the nginx and php-fpm configuration look on the web server (10.20.0.100)? Specifically, how can I configure it to work with the SSL certificate obtained from Certbot and handle requests for the WordPress site?

WordPress and SSL:
Are there any specific configurations within WordPress that need to be adjusted to work seamlessly with SSL? Any plugins or settings that should be considered?